# Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

In the following code i have error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;` in line 98 (this line has been determined in code), I want put codes in a function (like: `tooltip()`) but get error, how is fix it?

My code that have error:

```
function tool_tip() {
    $('.tooltip_hover').hover(function () {
        var $tooltip = $(this).prev();
        //var $tooltip = $('.tooltip');
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var delay = setTimeout(function () {
            $tooltip.fadeIn();

            var width = $tooltip.outerWidth();
            var p_top = offset.top;
            var tt_ht = $tooltip.height();
            p_top = (p_top + tt_ht > $(window).height()) ? p_top - tt_ht : p_top;
            var p_left = offset.right - width;

            $tooltip.css({
                top: p_top,
                right: p_left
            }).fadeIn(180);

        }, 280);

        $(this).data('delay', delay);
        $(this).data('tooltip', $tooltip);

    }, function () {
        delay = $(this).data('delay');
        $tooltip = $(this).data('tooltip');
        $('.tooltip').hide();
        clearInterval(delay);

    });
}); // this is line 98
```

Comment: You should make sure that "delay" and "$tooltip" are re-declared with `var` in the second "hover" function!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
}); // this is line 98
```

should be:

```
} // this is line 98
```

because `tool_tip` is a function, or match with an opening parenthesis:

```
(function tool_tip () {
    // stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have an extra ) at the very end.